# SQL Report Builder: get value from group within tablix

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Please forgive the vague title of this question. Perhaps the below will ask my question better.

Consider the below aggregated table:

```
Fruit   Units   FruitSales%
-----   -----   -----------
Apples     10             ?
Oranges    20             ?
Bananas    10             ?
NonFruit   10             ?

TOTAL      50             ?
```

I need the `FruitSales%` column to be: `Fruit / (Total - NonFruit)`

If NonFruit is a product name of its own, how do I get its value for use in other calculations in the tablix?

I imagine my formula for the FruitSales% is something like:

```
Sum(Fields!Units.Value) / (ReportItems!txtTotalUnits.Value - SumIf(Fields!Fruit = "NonFruit", Fields!Units.Value)
```

However, SumIf does not exist and even if it did, it would be specific to the current row.

And while I'm here, `ReportItems!txtTotalUnits.Value`, I have obviously named that text box, but is there a cleaner way to reference it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say the underlying DataSet (which I've called **FruitDataSet**) looks like this:

[image]

I've created a simple report based on this data:

[image]

The **Fruit Sales %** expression is:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!fruit.Value <> "NonFruit", Fields!units.Value, 0))
  / Sum(IIf(Fields!fruit.Value <> "NonFruit", Fields!units.Value, 0), "FruitDataSet")
```

This gives what I think is the correct results:

[image]

There are two things to note about the expression:

1. By running the `Sum` against an `IIf` expression, you can control what gets included in the totals - here I'm setting **NonFruit** explicitly to *0*.
2. By setting the **Scope** of the aggregate expression, you can get overall totals to use to work out total percentages - in the report I'm getting a total using **FruitDataSet** and comparing this to the group-level total to get a % value.

The way you're referencing the textbox total is fine; the only other option would be to use an expression each time you want the total - if this is outside a Tablix you would need to explicitly set the Scope, e.g. the DataSet.

Comment: Thank you very much Ian, that is perfect and so well explained. I really appreciate the time you spent on this!